# Get the path of a key from nested JSON using Json.Net

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, jpath

I have a big nested JSON. I don't know the structure of the JSON.
I just have a set of keys which are present in the JSON but I don't know where exactly in the JSON.
How do I find out the path of a key from an unknown JSON structure assuming the key exists somewhere in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your JSON structure is unknown, you can parse it into a [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) like this:

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
```

From there, you can use either [`SelectToken()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) or [`SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) with a recursive descent [JsonPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) expression to find the property (or properties) matching a key:

```
JToken match = token.SelectToken("$.." + keyToFind);
```

Once you have the matching token, you can get the path to it using its [`Path`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Path.htm) property:

```
string path = match?.Path;
```

Here is a working demo which assumes you have multiple keys to find and each key can appear multiple times in the JSON:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/9Em9Iq

Answer (score 0):

For an unknown structure you can iterate over the objects :

```
var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(jsonText))
while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Do a condition on the variables reader.TokenType, reader.ValueType, reader.Value

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(<yourjson>);
dynamic obj = o.SelectTokens("$..Product");
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will log all paths in your top level json that have a key equal to "key"

```
        var keys = jobject.Properties().Where(p => p.Name == key).ToList();

        keys.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.Path));
```

This will NOT work in a recursive way but it is easy from this to do a recursive search from there